# Installing and compiling log4cpp on Debian

Tags: linux, debian, software-installation, cpp

How to install log4cpp framework package stored locally as tar.gz, and which file from that package to use for bulding. I read some articles on internet, but I'm getting stucked at this part:

```
./configure
make
make check
make install
```

Can someone please explain me how to install and build app from tar.gz?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to follow this steps:

1. Extract the archive:

   `tar -xvzf log4cpp.tar.gz`
2. cd to created directory

   `cd log4cpp`
3. Run configure:

   `./configure`

You can check various options if you run: `./configure --help`. For example with option `--prefix=/path/` you can change installation directories, by default `make install` will install all the files in `/usr/local/bin` and `/usr/local/lib/`

3-1.  If you have error, configure: error: cannot guess build type; you must specify one, in `./configure`, please see [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6786522/5595995).

3-2.  `cmake .`

4. Run `make` to compile it:

   `make` or `make clean all`
5. Check building:

   `make check`

Final output could be:

```
===================
All 10 tests passed
===================
```

6. Run `make install` to install it:

   `make install`

### Alternative

I thought you want to compile it yourself but there is a package from Debian 8.1, so you can also install it with:

```
apt-get install liblog4cxx10 liblog4cxx10-doc
```

and it should install all required dependencies.
You can try to search the correct tool version with:

```
apt-cache search log4cxx
```

Comment: I tried with that, but Im getting errors @taliezin. Configure goes okay, but when i run make, it says "No such file or directory"

Comment: If it throws error may be `configure` does not run successful. Check output of `configure`.

Comment: There should be executable script `./configure` when you extract the archive.  The user who extract it can run it. It may fail if it can not find specific libray on system for example.

Comment: error: APR could not be located. Please use the --with-apr option

Comment: run this: `apt-get install libaprutil1-dev`